# Bessel function with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a vibrating membrane and therefor I need the bessel functions. As I'm using pgfplots, I wondered if there is anything pgf-related that can be used to create a corresponding output. I'm providing a MWE for playing around with the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot3[surf, z buffer=sort, domain=0:1, y domain=0:2*pi]
        ({x * cos(deg(y))}, {x * sin(deg(y))}, {cos(pi*x)});
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Has anybody a workaround or a way of using the functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Remarks

`pgfplots` offers to use the external programme `gnuplot` through

```
\addplot gnuplot {<gnuplot stuff>};
```

Review section 4.3.5 "Computing Coordinates with Mathematical Expressions" on page 56 of the [pgfplots 1.9 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

`gnuplot` provides the function [`besj0(r)`](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-5300013.1), that return the Bessel J0 function.

## Implementation

Use `arara` or `pdflatex -shell-escape`. You need `gnuplot` in your `$PATH`.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,domain=-2:2,y domain=-2:2] gnuplot {besj0(x**2+y**2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

---

You can also use the FFI in LuaJITTeX (and LuaTeX ≥ 1.0.3) to access the Bessel function in `libm` directly.  The performance and accuracy are simply amazing!  The `BesselJ` function takes two arguments where the first is the order of the Bessel function, i.e. all orders are directly accessible without having to use recurrence relations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\directlua{
  ffi=require("ffi")
  ffi.cdef[[
  double jn(int n, double x);
  ]]
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{BesselJ}{2}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
    \directlua{tex.print(ffi.C.jn(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2}))}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,domain=-2:2,y domain=-2:2] { BesselJ(0,x^2+y^2)) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's pretty much everything I could ever desire. Except: I didn't find any way in gnuplot to use `J_2`. I did only find the functions `besj0` and `besj1`. Is there any more general approach like `besj(n, x)` or something similar?

Comment: @HenriMenke: It may be worthwhile adding a note that one needs `lualatex -shell-escape` to run code with FFI.

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func,amsmath}

\psset{xunit=0.25,yunit=5}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-28,-.75)(29,1.2)
\rput(13,0.8){$\displaystyle J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos(x\sin t-nt)\,\mathrm{d}t$}
\psaxes[Dy=0.2,Dx=4]{->}(0,0)(-28,-.75)(28.5,1.15)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
\psBessel[linecolor=red]{0}{-28}{28}%
\psBessel[linecolor=blue]{1}{-28}{28}%
\psBessel[linecolor=green]{2}{-28}{28}%
\psBessel[linecolor=magenta]{3}{-28}{28}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive, thanks. I didn't know that PSTricks was *this* powerful!

Comment: A `\,` before `\mathrm{d}` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, height=0.5*\textwidth, xlabel=$x$]
    \addplot+[id=parable,domain=0:20, samples=500, mark=none, width=2pt]
    gnuplot{besj0(x)} node[pin=95:{$J_0(x)$}]{};
    \addplot+[id=parable,domain=0:20, samples=500, mark=none, width=2pt, color=red]
    gnuplot{besj1(x)} node[pin=130:{$J_1(x)$}]{};
    \addplot+[id=parable2,domain=0:20, samples=500, mark=none, width=2pt, color=black]
    gnuplot{2*1/x*besj1(x)-besj0(x)} node[pin=-140:{$J_2(x)$}]{};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please run with "pdflatex -shell-escape"

Here is the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Possible to use GNUplot for higher order Bessel's function also. One can use the recurrence formulas, http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bessel_functions

```
%For examples, plotting besj2(x)

\addplot[color=yellow,
solid,
line width=1.0pt,
%mark=asterisk,
%mark options={solid},
domain=0:5,samples=400]
gnuplot {abs(2*1/x * besj1(x) - besj0(x))};

%Similarly besj3(x) gnuplot {abs(2*2/x * besj2(x) - besj1(x))};
```

[image: Bessel's functions using GNUplot and pgfplots]

Comment: Thank you, that's actually *really* helpful! I didn't think of this forumla.