# Plot bessel functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot

Is there any way of producing first and second kind bessel functions?

[image]

What about modified bessel functions?

I want to have `J_{\nu} (x)` , `Y_{\nu} (x)`, `I_{\nu} (x)` and `K_{\nu} (x)` in a separate figure like attached picture!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160748/bessel-function-with-pgfplots perhaps

Comment: with external calls, you can plot whatever gnuplot supports

Comment: @percusse what's external call??

Comment: see the linked question

Comment: If you already have a mean for computing the values (e.g., scipy) it is pretty straightforward to parse a CSV file with Lua and generate the relevant TikZ bits.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the FFI in LuaJITTeX (and LuaTeX ≥ 1.0.3) to access the Bessel function in `libm` directly.  The performance and accuracy are simply amazing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\directlua{
  ffi=require("ffi")
  ffi.cdef[[
  double jn(int n, double x);
  double yn(int n, double x);
  ]]
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{BesselJ}{2}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
    \directlua{tex.print(ffi.C.jn(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2}))}%
  }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{BesselY}{2}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
    \directlua{tex.print(ffi.C.yn(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2}))}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    cycle list={[samples of colormap={6 of viridis}]},
    enlargelimits=false,
    domain=0:20,
    restrict y to domain=-2:1,
    ymin=-1,
    samples=100,
    no markers]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,2}{
      \addplot { BesselJ(#1,x) }; \addlegendentry{$J_{#1}(x)$};
    }
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,2}{
      \addplot { BesselY(#1,x) }; \addlegendentry{$Y_{#1}(x)$};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're not stuck to using TiKZ, `pstricks` can plot Bessel functions of all orders, and modified Bessel functions of 1st order, via the `pst-func` package and the `\psBessel` and `\psModBessel` macros. See §§4-5 of the pst-func documentation.

Comment: Can you do an example like picture?

Comment: Very easily. I don't have the time at the moment, but I'll add an example  later today.

Comment: @H.H Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160750/586?

Comment: Yes! But what about Y_{\nu} and K_{\nu}??

Comment: It doesn't plot them, and as the macro if for `plotting`, not for entering the values of the functions, I don't see how to do. You might ask one of the authors, Manuel Luque or Herbert Voss.

Answer (score 3):

run with `xelatex` or with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.25,yunit=5}
\begin{pspicture}(-30,-.85)(30,1.25)
\rput(13,0.8){%
    $\displaystyle J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos(x\sin t-nt)\mathrm{d}t$}
\psaxes[Dy=0.2,Dx=4]{->}(0,0)(-30,-.8)(30,1.2)
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
\psBessel[linecolor=red]{0}{-28}{28}%
\psBessel[linecolor=blue]{1}{-28}{28}%
\psBessel[linecolor=green]{2}{-28}{28}%
\psBessel[linecolor=magenta]{3}{-28}{28}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
% !TEX program = LuaLaTeX
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%%---------------------------
\begin{luacode*}
local kner = function(n,x,t)
return math.cos(x*math.sin(t)-n*t)
end

local bessel = function(m,n,x)
local summ =0.0
local pi=3.1415
for k=1, m do
tk=k*pi/m
summ = summ+kner(n,x,tk)
end
return summ/m
end
thirddata = thirddata or {}
thirddata.bessel = function(m,n,x)
return tex.print(bessel(m,n,x))
end
\end{luacode*}
%%---------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[pb]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm, height=7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={
bessel(\m,\n,\x) = \directlua{thirddata.bessel(\m,\n,\x)};
}]

\begin{axis}[
use fpu=false,
xmin=-30, xmax=30,
ymin=-1, ymax=1.2,
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
axis lines = middle,
]
\addplot[red,thick,domain=-28:28,samples=1000] (x,{bessel(200,0,x)});
\addlegendentry{ $ J_{0}(x)$}
\addplot[green,thick,domain=-28:28,samples=1000] (x,{bessel(200,1,x)});
\addlegendentry{ $ J_{1}(x)$}
\addplot[blue,thick,domain=-28:28,samples=1000] (x,{bessel(200,2,x)});
\addlegendentry{ $ J_{2}(x)$}
\addplot[yellow,thick,domain=-28:28,samples=1000] (x,{bessel(200,3,x)});
\addlegendentry{ $ J_{3}(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ $J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos(x\sin t-nt)\mathrm{d}t$ }
\end{figure}

\[ J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos(x\sin t-nt)\mathrm{d}t \]

We use the composite trapezoidal Rule to approximate this definite integral by a sum of finite terms

\[ J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos(x\sin t-nt)\mathrm{d}t \approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \cos(x \sin t_k-n t_k)\]
where $t_k=k \frac{\pi}{m}$
\end{document}
```