# Error with LuaTeX and pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, texstudio

This question is strictly related to [a previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456747/plot-bessel-functions-with-pgfplots): I have tried to test the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456772/74786), which uses LuaTeX and pgfplots. Using TeXstudio 2.12.6 with Qt 5.9.5 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, before the code I put the line

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
```

This generates an error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'BesselJ(0,x)'). }.
```

LuaLaTeX runs with:

```
lualatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

And PdfLaTeX runs with:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Please note that the code [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368692/74786) works instead, with the same settings.

I have installed all the packages `gsl-*`.

How to fix this?

---

Here it is the MWE, which can be simply desumed from the question.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
local ffi = require("ffi")
gsl = ffi.load("gsl")

ffi.cdef[[
double gsl_sf_bessel_Jn(int n, double x);
double gsl_sf_bessel_Yn(int n, double x);
double gsl_sf_bessel_In(int n, double x);
double gsl_sf_bessel_Kn(int n, double x);
]]
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\declarebesselfunction[1]{%
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{Bessel#1}{2}{%
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{%
      \directlua{tex.print(gsl.gsl_sf_bessel_#1n(
        \pgfmathfloatvalueof{##1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{##2}))}%
    }%
  }%
}

\declarebesselfunction{J}
\declarebesselfunction{Y}
\declarebesselfunction{I}
\declarebesselfunction{K}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[samples=100,no marks,restrict y to domain=-3:3]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,5}{
      \addplot+[domain=0:10] {BesselJ(#1,x)};
      \addplot+[domain=.001:10] {BesselY(#1,x)};
      \addplot+[domain=0:10] {BesselI(#1,x)};
      \addplot+[domain=.001:10] {BesselK(#1,x)};
    }
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could be a red herring but you'll be told by others to give a mwe However if we accept you would simply copy and paste the content  of the links given we see that working only uses ffi but non working depends also on gsl (an external resource) much similar to the need to add gnuplot (which actually is NOTgnu) to your path. So my main question is can you call the relevant part of gsl manually from ANY remote command line (shell escape)

Comment: My bad I assumed gsl is executable whilst looking closer it is a FFI called component So I guess you need to manually call FFI (which you can since that call works) and get confirmatory feedback as to if it found and ran gsllib since at present it seems not since the result is Could not parse input '   ' as a floating point number i.e I got nothing back

Comment: Looks like your running on Linux so I'm not much help on how you can get gsl to print back "hello BowPark" and there seems to be no such simple call as tell me your version unless its as a string like gsl_major_version (not much help if it just says "2" ). perhaps you could use the simplest construct rather than Bessel or try to catch the results by changing say the first "double gsl_sf_bessel_Jn(int n, double x);" so that becomes "double gsl_sf_bessel_J0(0, double x);" also looks like there may not be a need for the comma so also try it without

Comment: Just for the records: I cannot run the linked code either on my updated TeXLive 2018 distribution even though I compile with `lualatex -shell-escape`. Yet I get a different error.

Comment: @marmot (see your headed for marmot of the quarter, congrats) the issue here is gsl code via ffi on Linux not works versus ffi code alone works are you able to confirm with mwe for OP how gsl code can be verified as available? I drilled down to the uncompiled C code and syntax seems slightly different to other methods listed so something as simple as a misplaced variable or separator may give a null result

Comment: @KJO I really do not know what happens on two practically identical computers I get different results: on one it generates an error but on the other one not. Now I am sitting at the computer on which it works. No idea what's going on.

Comment: @marmot I can test ffi with this link https://mytexpert.osdn.jp/index.php?LuaLaTeX mwe at bottom of page however I  have no mwe for gsl or know which/where version Is good for windows

Comment: @KJO I just edited the question with mwe and more details. Sorry, I can't follow all your considerations: what test should I run? I tried using only `double gsl_sf_bessel_Jn(0, double x);`, but the error is the same. Your [linked code](https://mytexpert.osdn.jp/index.php?LuaLaTeX) prints as LaTeX paragraph text all the code between `\begin{luacode*}` and `\end{luacode*}`, also violating the page right border.

Comment: There are several parts to this issue 1) you must be running LuaLatex with --shell-escape active so that Lua can call ffi The above linked code works on windows to prove via a system message box that Lualatex uses via shell-escape some C code to generate a system message to screen. 2) the gsllib must be available to ffi thus Henri has given you the system update and importantly an install command for libgsl-dev. Once all is correctly in place then your test.tex should run similar to how his copy did from the command line. In short TeX is good but DEPENDS on a valid environment being in place.

Comment: It sometimes helps if I try to explain what your hoping to achieve in reverse SO good Bessel routine is written in C or C+ or any other high level math code that has been stored as a routine in a GNU library, once that is in place we need to call that Foreign library with  an interface (FFI) which Lua can make the structured call to get a valid return to plot (1) we can use Lua(La)TeX (2) it must call FFI, to do that it NEEDS write18 privilege (shell-escape) (3) ffi finds (by default) the installed gsl lib (4) gsl responds to the call with a stream of data (5) ffi passes the result back to Lua

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your problem with the Ubuntu 18.04 Docker container.  I start the container using

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`:/test ubuntu:bionic
```

and then inside the container I run

```bash
cd /test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-binaries texlive-pictures texlive-latex-base texlive-luatex libgsl-dev
lualatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

It all works without problems.  Running `pdfinfo` on the resulting PDF on the host system, shows

```
$ pdfinfo test.pdf 
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       LuaTeX-1.0.4
[...snip...]
```

Here a screenshot of the PDF:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much anyway for having tried. Maybe, like @marmot says in the comments, it is dependent on the specific system, for some mysterious reason. If I have the occasion to test it in another system, I will try.