# How to plot a custom bessel function?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The function is a composition function with Bessel function as a part of a complex function.

[image]

Where `J_0` is the bessel function

Comment: Are you able to use tikz-pgf to plot cos(100x)/(x^2+1)?  Could you show us a MWE that does so?  You wrote "Where J_0 is (a function in terms of J_0)."  Did you mean to write "How can I plot the function (a function in terms of J_0), where J_0 is a Bessel function (of type ...)"?

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant the function is `cos(100x)/(x^2+1)*J_0(170x)` .

Comment: `\begin{asy}   \end{asy}` can not be surrounded by `\begin{axis}   \end{axis}` or `\begin{tikzpicture}   \end{tikzpicture}`. They are totally different environments.

Comment: For alignment, this may help https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/2Dgraphs/alignedaxis.asy

Comment: @Teepeemm , I tried to work out but could not get the desired result. May you kindly help.

Comment: @Formal_this From the updated question, I still don't get exactly what issue you want to  fix. Can you describe in more details?

Comment: @BlackMild , Sure. `1.` The bessel function plot is not of correct size, as the other 3 plots are. It looks . `2.` The legend of the bessel function is coming out of the plot. `3.` The x and y labels of the bessel function is not coming in boldface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** It seems that OP want this one:

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
usepackage("amsmath"); 
import graph;  
size(12cm,8cm,IgnoreAspect); 
real xmin=1,xmax=2, ymin=-.03,ymax=.03; 
pair f(real x){return (x,Jn(0,170x)*cos(100x)/(x^2+1));} 
guide gf=graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=1000);
draw((1,0)--(2,0),gray);
draw(gf,blue+.8pt); 
label("$F(x)=\dfrac{\cos(100x)}{x^2+1}J_0(170x)$",(2,.02),4W); xaxis("$\mathbf{x}$",BottomTop,LeftTicks); yaxis("$\mathbf{F(x)}$",LeftRight,RightTicks);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

---

**Old:** An Asymptote plot (https://www.overleaf.com/read/mvryqvrtgqrp)

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import graph; 
size(12cm,8cm,IgnoreAspect);
real xmin=1,xmax=2, ymin=-.03,ymax=.03;
pair f(real x){return (x,Jn(0,170x)*cos(100x)/(x^2+1));}
guide gf=graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=1000);
draw(gf,red);
xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$F(x)$",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));
label("Levin function $F(x)=\frac{\cos(100x)}{x^2+1}J_0(170x)$",point(N),2N);
```

Comment: That looks great. Is it a standalone plot? I am not able to compile this on overleaf. Do I need to make some changes? I didn't understand Asymptote plot.

Comment: @Formal_this Try reading through chapter 7 of the Asymptote documentation: https://ctan.org/pkg/asymptote.  You can surround this with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[inline]{asymptote} \begin{document} \begin{asy}` and `\end{asy} \end{document}` to get this to compile in Overleaf.

Comment: @Teepeemm I tried to include this code and your suggestion in my code. But I am having trouble to position it in my subfigure properly. Do you have any idea what may help? Thanks again.

Comment: @Formal_this Remove the `{tikzpicture}` and `{axis}` environments?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yeah, that actually works, now how to get the label inside the function box ? Also, making the axis label f(x) and x as bold.  Thank

Comment: @Formal_this Making the axis label f(x) and x as bold is just a LaTeX stuff,`$\mathbf{F(x)}$`. What do you mean by *the label inside the function box* ? Anyway, I have just added an overleaf link.

Comment: @Formal_this Have a look here https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/2Dgraphs/ to adapt to your need

Comment: @BlackMild How to get the legend of the function inside the plot. Thanks

Comment: Like this? `usepackage("amsmath");
import graph; 
size(12cm,8cm,IgnoreAspect);
real xmin=1,xmax=2, ymin=-.03,ymax=.03;
pair f(real x){return (x,Jn(0,170x)*cos(100x)/(x^2+1));}
guide gf=graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=1000);
draw(gf,red);
label("$F(x)=\dfrac{\cos(100x)}{x^2+1}J_0(170x)$",(2,.02),2W);
xaxis("$\mathbf{x}$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$\mathbf{F(x)}$",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));
`

Comment: @BlackMild , I tried to include this as well. But some issues are still there. I have updated the question. Can you have a look.

Comment: @BlackMild , The subfigure of bessel's function is not of the same size and shape as that of the other figures. Also, the font of the plot is not consistent.

Answer (score 2):

The open source computer algebra system, SAGE, knows about [bessel functions](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/bessel.html) and the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package lets you access it for your LaTeX documents. This makes sure the calculations are correct; with complicated functions like yours, the accuracy of `pgfplots` tends to struggle.
By using the `sagetex` package you can plot the coordinates (created by SAGE) with `pgfplots`.

Here is sample code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
f=cos(100*x)/(x^2+1)*bessel_J(0,170*x)
step = .001
x_coords = [x for x in srange(1,2+step,step)]
y_coords = [f(x=x).n(digits=4) for x in x_coords]
output = r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=1,xmax=2,ymin=-.03,ymax=.03]"
output += r"\addplot[thin, blue, smooth] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x_coords)-1):
    output += r"(%f , %f) "%(x_coords[i],y_coords[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output in Cocalc looks like this:

[image]

SAGE isn't part of your LaTeX distribution. The easiest way to experiment with it is by creating a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account--you'll be done in less than 5 minutes. It's also possible to download SAGE to your computer and get it to communicate with your LaTeX distribution but this will take more time and can be more difficult.

Comment: Hey can you check whether this can be included in the subfigure or not. Kindly see the the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: The only thing that `sagetex` is doing in my code is creating the coordinates. It has to work but we've drifted very far from your original post.

Comment: sure, thanks for the help.